# How to migrate Data from one hyperledger fabric Network to another Hyperledger fabric network?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, hyperledger-chaincode, hyperledger-fabric-ca

Is there any way to migrate data from one hyperledger fabric network to another hyperledger fabric network with same structure but different `certs` .

Answer (score -1):

A possible option could be to extract all history of transaction data and then write to new network

Comment: How should one go about extracting this history of transaction data?